# .click() is called at times when there is no click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have added a `.click` function to a input button type inside a JavaScript function.
 The `.Click` function calls another JavaScript function. But for some reason the `.click` function is called all the time. Even when there is no clicks on the element.
 Below is my code. Thanks for helping me out.

```
function loadBook(URL) {
    alert(URL);
};

function LoadAllBooks(URL, attachPoint) {
    var title = "This is some code bad code";
    var classname = title.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var htmlString = '<div class="' + classname + '"><input type="button" value="' + title + '"></div>';
    $(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(loadBook(URL));
};
```

**attachPoint** is a reference in the HTML which is got by the following line.

```
 var attachpoint=document.querySelector('.buttonAttachPoint');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy mistake. By including the `(URL)` parameter there, you're actually calling the `loadBook` function immediately, rather than supplying `loadBook` as the click handler.

What you need to do is more like:

```
$(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click( function(){ loadBook(URL) } );
```

Create an anonymous function that runs loadBook, rather than running loadBook directly.